# Adding a class object from a list to a QWidget

Tags: python, list, pyqt, qwidget

I am trying to add a class object from a list as a `QWidget` to a `QSplitter` .

This is the code:

```
class Windows(QMainWindow):

  list_1 = []

  def __init__(self):
    #Some stuff in here
    self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

  def methodA(self):
    plot = Plot()

    Windows.list_1.append(plot)
    self.splitter.addwidget(???)    #Here is where i want to put the specific class object 
                                    #from the list

class Plot():
  #this is a Matplotlib figure
```

First, i call the class object `plot` and i append it to `list_1` when i push a combination of keys, then i need to add that specific object, from the list, in the`QSplitter` using `addWidget`.

How can i do this? Hope you can help me.

I need to do this, in order to identify the object from the list, so later i can create another method to delete this object from the splitter.

Comment: What about using a dictionary?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the difference?

Comment: Are you trying to add the item that your just added to the list or a different item in the list?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The item i just added to the list.

Comment: You could identify your object with a dictionary like: `myDict["myObject"] = myObject` so you don't have to worry about the index

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a reference to the object you want to add to the QSplitter, you don't need to pull it out of the list.

```
def methodA(self):
    plot = Plot()

    Windows.list_1.append(plot)
    self.splitter.addwidget(plot)
```

If you didn't have a reference to the widget, but wanted to item that was most recently added to the list, you can use negative list indexing -

```
def methodA(self):
    plot = Plot()

    Windows.list_1.append(plot)
    self.splitter.addwidget(Windows.list_1[-1])
```